# Recover Git local repository

Tags: git, recover

If I have a Git account on, say, GitHub, and previously I have set up the local repository, have committed and pushed several times.

Now I have carelessly deleted the local repository (.git), but the remote repository is still there in GitHub, how can I rebuild the deleted local repository and continue to commit and push without harming the old commits?

Comment: You can clone it again.

Comment: By "local repo" do you mean just the `.git` subdirectory?

Comment: I suppose you could 1) back up your working directory, 2) `git clone` a fresh repo from github, 3) copy your working directory into the fresh repo, overwriting any existing files.

Answer (score 4):

If you have deleted the local repository, but you have pushed your commits to the GitHub repository, you only need to re-clone the project by doing `git clone <url>`, and your work is ready...

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize a new Git repository in your machine:

```
git init
```

Add your remote repository (published on GitHub):

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/exampleusername/example_repo.git
```

fetch the origin:

```
git fetch
```

Then you can update your local branch with any branch you want:

```
git pull origin example_branch_name_you_want_to_take_update_from
```

Or you can simply clone the existing remote repository as suggested in the above comments:

```
git clone https://your_repot_url
```

Comment: What's the advanteges of init + fetch ovet clone?

Comment: @bimlas I suppose this is an approach for a pre-existing working-tree.

Comment: I think there shouldn't be a direct answer, git fetch and git clone both have different advantages based on their usage. If you want to work directly from a remote repo and have the remote tracking branches, clone is ok where  fetch is used to fetch updates( from a specific point).